# Can OAuth 2 be used for SSO? Or do I need a more sophisticated authentication?

Tags: authentication, drupal, oauth, single-sign-on, identity

We're going to use drupal as a portal, but authentication should be external to drupal. This is the first step for a future architecture. In the future, other applications should be able to use the same authentication architecture (as well as identity and profiles).

We're also going to have some initial REST APIs (e.g. PubSub).

We will use OAuth for the REST API authentication.

But what about future web front end applications? Would they also use OAuth? Or do I need to think of a more sophisticated authentication infrastructure?

Answer (score 2):

In general, you shouldn't be relying strictly on OAuth2 for authentication as **OAuth2 is an authorization mechanism, not an authentication mechanism**.  Though, if you're stuck with it, and you understand the security implications, you can use my [OAuth2 Authentication](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauth2_authentication) module in Drupal.

The problem is that you have no guarantee that the resource requester is actually the resource owner.  These two articles provide more detail on this, and explain real-world problems associated with it:

- [Why OAuth it self is not an authentication
  framework?](http://blog.api-security.org/2013/02/why-oauth-it-self-is-not-authentication.html)
- [The problem with OAuth for
  Authentication](http://www.thread-safe.com/2012/01/problem-with-oauth-for-authentication.html)

You should really be setting up [OpenID Connect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID_Connect) as it provides an authentication layer on top of OAuth2.  Although [SAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) has been used traditionally, it it rather dated and isn't as versatile as OpenID Connect over OAuth2.  As time goes on, we'll probably start seeing the Web move towards OpenID Connect, and away from SAML.

This is from the [OpenID Connect FAQ](http://openid.net/connect/faq/):

> The Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) is an XML-based
>   federation technology used in some enterprise and academic use cases.
>   OpenID Connect can satisfy these same use cases but with a simpler,
>   JSON/REST based protocol. OpenID Connect was designed to also support
>   native apps and mobile applications, whereas SAML was designed only
>   for Web-based applications. SAML and OpenID Connect will likely
>   coexist for quite some time, with each being deployed in situations
>   where they make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use SSO, the option you have will be SAML SSO or OpenId.
For API security you can use OAuth and for SSO you can use either of above. If you move forward with SAML SSO, then there is this specification which address the scenario at [1].

Link [2] will give some insight on how it's used in real world scenarios. Simply in this combination, you can exchange a SAML token received in SSO step to get a Oauth token which will be valid to access the APIs.

[1] - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-saml2-bearer-18

[2] - http://nallaa.wordpress.com/2013/04/04/saml2-bearer-assertion-profile-for-oauth-2-0-with-wso2-identity-server/

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out the links!